# Average value of normal distribution above two standard deviations

Tags: normal-distribution

Let's say IQ or any other normal distributed value. How do I calculate the average score/value of all values above two standard deviations? I mean the theoretical average, not given any concrete set of values.

Comment: So I think, what you're essentially trying to calculate is
$$
\int_2^{\infty} x \cdot \exp ( -\frac{1}{2}x^2 )\, dx
$$

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/136247/calculating-mean-and-variance-of-normal-distribution-restricted-to-interval

Comment: Yes, or the value x1 with which the integral above from 2 to x1 gives half the value of the one above.